# Cloud IAP and three-legged OAuth

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-platform

Assuming the following scenario:

```
User <> Cloud IAP <> App Engine App <> Google APIs
```

How can `App Engine App` access `Google APIs` on behalf of the authenticated user? (i.e., not using the App Engine App service account)

`Cloud IAP` transmits a JWT token to `App Engine App`, but I could not use it to access `Google APIs` resources (the user profile for example).

I could not find any relevant documentation for that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Apps don't automatically get to call APIs on behalf of their users, even if it is behind Cloud IAP. Cloud IAP exists to control access to the apps, not grant apps permissions.

To allow apps to act on behalf of users, the app will have to do [the OAuth2.0 web server flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer). Typically you will use a google provided oauth2 library to do that flow ([python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#OAuth2WebServerFlow), [java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications), [etc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#libraries)) and then pass that credential into the client library you are using to make the actual API call.

Comment: Does this mean there will be at least two OAuth user requests made: 
1 - for IAP to grant control access to the app
2 - and then another user request for app level permissions (for example accessing Bigquery, storage etc.)

Comment: Correct.

The IAP JWT you mention is an assertion, signed by IAP, that the request came from a given user. It isn't a credential that you can use to make requests.